# Not able to load c3 graph data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, graph, c3.js

HI i want to load dynamic data with date time range with c3 graph 
Here is my CODE :

```
$.ajax({
    [...]
    success: function(data) {
        chart.load({
            columns: data,
            unload: chart.columns,
        });
    }
});
```

The Ajax response is  :

```
[['Friday', 1],['Friday', 3],['Sunday', 1],['Saturday', 2],['Friday', 3],['Friday', 3],['Friday', 5],['Friday', 3],['Monday', 1],['Friday', 1],['Tuesday', 1]]
```

On success haven't seen anything on my graph . even i have commented "unload"
but still same  . the function is works fine if i put statically . please help  me

Comment: Is it working now?

Answer (score 1):

You're using it wrong. It's not exporting a `chart` function, but a `c3` function. The following will generate a chart (that doesn't look too good but I don't know what you're expecting).

You also missed to define an output div, thus I added `#chart`.

```js
var data = [['Friday', 1],['Friday', 3],['Sunday', 1],['Saturday', 2],['Friday', 3],['Friday', 3],['Friday', 5],['Friday', 3],['Monday', 1],['Friday', 1],['Tuesday', 1]];

var data2 = [['Friday', 3],['Friday', 10],['Sunday', 50],['Saturday', 20],['Friday', 15],['Friday', 10],['Friday', 6],['Friday', 8],['Monday', 5],['Friday', 20],['Tuesday', 13]];

var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
      columns: data
    }
});

setTimeout(function() {
    chart.load({
        columns: data2 
    });
}, 2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.11/c3.js"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: I know its works  , but have u try to update by using AJAX

Comment: I added a delayed update to show how to update it. Is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try brackets around columns: data in the chart.load function argument ? Here is a piece of code which works in my application

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnPDquant", function(event) {
$.ajax({ 
url: "PDQuantCalc",
type: "post",
data: $('#formPDquant').serialize(), 
success: function(response){
    var newdat = JSON.parse(response);
    chart.x(newdat.year);
        chart.load({
            columns: [ newdat.PDquant ]
    });
}
event.preventDefault(); // Important! Prevents submitting the form.
});
```